# Cannot be reached to Sonarqube from Jenkins on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, sonarqube, ssl-certificate, sonarqube-scan

I have installed below things on AWS EC2 CentOS instance:
-   Nginx
-   Sonarqube server
-   Sonar scanner
-   SSL Certificate named as Jenkins
My Sonar is installed on port 9000 and below is the URL to access it as SSL certificate is installed on this machine.
https://jenkins.net/sonar/

Below are other details:

**nginx.conf**

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.

    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/jenkins.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/ssl/jenkins.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location /
        {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_read_timeout  90;


      # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_request_buffering off;

    }

        location /nagios{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8093/nagios;
        }

        location /sonar{
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/sonar;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

}
```

**Sonarqube server configuration file:**

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SERVER
# The default value is root context (empty value).
sonar.web.context=/sonar
# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Default value is 9000.
#sonar.web.port=9000
```

**Sonar Scanner Configuration file:**

```
sonar.host.url=https://jenkins.net/sonar
```

Here I tried all below things like:

```
sonar.host.url=http://jenkins.net/sonar
                and
sonar.host.url=http://<my_ip_addr>/sonar
```

However in all cases, I am facing below issue:

```
[CS_Sonar] $ /opt/sonar_scanner/bin/sonar-scanner -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake -Dsonar.host.url=https://jenkins.net/dde/sonar ******** -Dproject.settings=/home/ubuntu/workspace/CS_Sonar/sonar.properties -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/home/ubuntu/workspace/CS_Sonar
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar_scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/ubuntu/workspace/CS_Sonar/sonar.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.3.0.1492
INFO: Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.15.0-1032-aws amd64
INFO: User cache: /home/ubuntu/.sonar/cache
ERROR: SonarQube server [https://jenkins.net/dde/sonar] can not be reached
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 0.333s
INFO: Final Memory: 5M/241M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute SonarQube
ERROR: Caused by: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
ERROR: Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
ERROR: Caused by: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
ERROR: Caused by: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succedeed?
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone of you please help on this. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "SSL certificates are installed on this machine"? Did you also properly add them to your java keystore? that java can verify the ssl certificate on the machine the scanner is running?

Comment: Yes I tried but no luck. Below was the command I used for this:

./keytool -import -alias sonarqube -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file jenkins.crt

In the folder:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin